# FIND items in list using lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have following classes:

```
public class AuthenticateCustomerResponse
{
    public EligiblePromotions EligiblePromotions { get; set; }
}

public class EligiblePromotions
{
    public List<PromotionList> PromotionList { get; set; }
}
public class PromotionList
{
    public string LineOfBusiness { get; set; }
    public AuthenticatePromotions Promotions { get; set; }
}
public class AuthenticatePromotions
{
    public List<AuthenticatePromotion> Promotion { get; set; }
}
public class AuthenticatePromotion
{
    public string ServiceType { get; set; }
}
```

I want to retrieve `PromotionList` whose `LineOfBusiness` is equal to "VID" and `ServiceType` is equal to "SAT".
I tried following lambda expression:

```
PromotionList getPromotion = AuthenticateCustomerResponse.EligiblePromotions.PromotionList.Find(p => p.LineOfBusiness.ToUpper().Equals("VID")).Promotions.Promotion.Find(o=>o.ServiceType.Equals("SAT"));
```

but I'm getting error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'AuthenticatePromotion' to
>   'PromotionList'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The naming of your properties and class names is terrible. Use FirstOrDefault or Where it will be easier.

Comment: @Silvermind Post edited

Comment: You are retrieving an `AuthenticatePromotion` object from your `Promotion` list. If you only want the `PromotionList`, why do you have another `Find`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code below will get you the first object whose `LineOfBusiness` equals to 'VID'.

```
var promotionList = AuthenticateCustomerResponse.EligiblePromotions.PromotionList
.Where(p => p.LineOfBusiness.ToUpper().Equals("VID")).FirstOrDefault();
```

You can use `.ToList()` if you want all objects that have VID as `LineOfBusiness` instead of `.FirstOrDefault()`

Edit: You can add another clause to your `.Where()` if you want to check for the SAT

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<PromotionList>' to 'PromotionList'

Comment: ToList returns in a list of objects which pass your Where clause. If you only want one object, select one from the list or use FirstOrDefault

Comment: Just a tip: I would rethink the way you have implemented your classes. It doesn't make much sense to create a reference to a class which only contains a list. You could make your life a lot easier and move the list to PromotionList

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code

```
.Promotion.Find(o=>o.ServiceType.Equals("SAT"));
```

Returns an `AuthenticatePromotion`, but you are explicitly asking for a `PromotionList` object.

One way to get rid of the error would be to use the implicit variable keyword `var`:

```
var getPromotion = AuthenticateCustomerResponse.EligiblePromotions.PromotionList.Find(p => p.LineOfBusiness.ToUpper().Equals("VID")).Promotions.Promotion.Find(o=>o.ServiceType.Equals("SAT"));
```

But then this will of course still return an `AuthenticatePromotion`

Comment: Maybe my query is wrong. Do you think the query is correct to retrieve `PromotionList` whose `LineOfBusiness` is equal to "VID" and `ServiceType` is equal to "SAT ?

Comment: @zariakhan I think that may depend on the rest of your application, although I must say with such a long line I would recommend placing the entire query into a method with a sensible name to improve readability